# Modifying css class with angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to change the class of selected button in an input radio group. Each button represent one seat, and then the total selected will be displayed.

```
   $scope.calculateChecked = function() {
      var count = 0;
      
      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value) {
        if(value.checked)
          count++;
      });
      
      return count;
   };
```

Here's my plunker sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wKzcz6TbYmfbL5mW?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

What I'm trying to accomplished is that when a particular seat selected (ie: seat 4), then all the previous seat (1,2,3) will be selected automatically, and then calculated as 4 seats price, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfoIV.png)

I know I'm using a veeery dated version, but I'm still learning the basic.

Thanks in advance for all help and suggestion, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my [Demo](http://plnkr.co/plunk/koMe71Mzdv2e7if2?preview) with Plunker.

**In your view:** instead of having a `show` property use the `user.checked` property of your model, so that you don't have to synchronise both values.

```html
<label style="width:100px;padding: 13px;border-radius: 5px;background: dimgray;
       text-align: center;color: white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -4px rgba(140,140,140,1);" 
       ng-class="{checked: user.checked}">
<input type="checkbox" style="display:none" value="1" name="options" 
       ng-model="user.checked" ng-click="userClick(user)"/>
<i class="fas fa-couch h2 px-2"></i><br />
${{price}}
{{ x }}
</label>
```

**Controller:** add this function

```js
$scope.userClick = function(user) {
    if(user.checked) {
       var i = 0;       
       while($scope.data[i].name != user.name)
       {
          $scope.data[i].checked = true;
          i++;
       };
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot for the response, man... It does work..

Comment: Although, pardon my newbieness.. I tried to implement your code in mine, it doesn't work... I even tried with a simple file, trying to tackle maybe there's a function conflict or some sort with mine, but still wont work..

Here's your plunker implemented from scratch..
http://prestigeair.bisapunya.com/cindy/?

Can you enlight me, please? Been stuck several days trying to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: There are other issues on the page you mention. For you to use bootstrap.min.js you need to add jquery library before in your html code. This doesn't happen in Plunker because they load jquery outside your code.

Comment: Yup, already added jquery cdn now. Still doesn't work.. Is there anything else missing from the plunker?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer with new version of `userClick()` function. That should work after deployed in your website. Plunker behaves differently when running same Angularjs snippet and it's using newer version of the framework.